# Gitlab: job variables not getting assigned before rules?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to control the job using variables. But this `.gitlab-ci.yml` is not working (job is skipped). Are not the job variables assigned before rules evaluations?

```
variables:
  GLOBAL_VAR: "true"

build:
  image: ubuntu
  variables:
    LOCAL_VAR: $GLOBAL_VAR
  script:
    - "echo 'ok'"
  rules:
    - if: '$LOCAL_VAR == "true"'
      when: always
```

best regards to all

Bruno Massa

Answer (score 0):

The rules are evaluated before any jobs run . https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

Answer (score 0):

*[EDIT: I've found that, while the solution bellow do get the value of GLOBAL_VAR to LOCAL_VAR, if you overwrite it's value in the Gitlab interface, it will not reflect here]*

I found a solution: using !reference keyword (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags). It is evaluated before rules!

```
.build-variables:
  variables:
    GLOBAL_VAR: "true"

build:
  image: ubuntu
  variables:
    LOCAL_VAR: !reference [.build-variables, variables, GLOBAL_VAR]
  script:
    - "echo 'ok'"
  rules:
    - if: '$LOCAL_VAR == "true"'
      when: always
```